# Yeoman - php project

Tags: php, gruntjs

I'm starting a new php project and I'm trying to learn new techniques (for me). Grunt, yeoman etc.

Now I want to start a php project and found this example from [Bradleycorn => generator-php](https://github.com/Bradleycorn/generator-php). As far as I think, I have everything working, but I can't rund my development local site using `grunt server`. I'm getting a error:

```
Running "php:server" (php) task
Invalid address: http://localhost/myproject.nl:80
```

I have this folder structure:
`\Applications\XAMPP\xamppfiles\htdocs\myproject.nl\`
Beneath this folder:

```
myproject\
 |--.sass-cache\
 |--.tmp\
 |--app\
 |--dist\
 |--node_modules\
 |--bower.json
 |--Grunftile.js
 |--package.jason
 |--router-dist.php
 |--router.php
```

In the `Gruntfile.js` this code is placed (part of the code with the dev URL):

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // CONFIGURABLE PATHS
    //  The yeomanConfig object contains file paths and other "constants" that are used throughout
    //  The rest of this Gruntfile. Basically, any value that is used in multiple places should be
    //  put here for ease of maintenance. Update the value here, and all other places are updated
    //  automagically.
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist',
        siteURL: 'www.myproject.nl',
        devURL: 'http://localhost/myproject.nl',
        devPort: 80
    };
```

I also tried this devURL `http://localhost/myproject.nl/myproject/dist:`, but also not working. What should the `devURL` be in this case?

**PS**: I also want to run a local database, I'm using XAMPP for that.

Comment: @kendall, no, I haven't.

Comment: I think i may have a solution but still working on it....but some insight...

I'm using grunt to compile a development configuration that copies files from "./app" to "xampp/htdocs/app" instead of ".tmp" then trying to use *browser-sync* to watch the files in xampp while grunt watched "./app" and updates "xampp". I have gotten it to work except for the browser sync part....